# How to get cookie using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cookies

I'm converting a java applet program to ipad version.

In the original java applet code, there are some code to get cookie from javascript:

```
    JSObject browser = (JSObject) JSObject.getWindow(this);
    JSObject document =  (JSObject) browser.getMember("document");
    String cookie = (String)document.getMember("cookie");
```

So, how can I get this cookie using objective-c? Are there any similar classes or methods that can do the same thing? Thanks. :)

========UPDATE========

```
NSString *cookie = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.cookie"];
```

using this method can read values from javascript code

Comment: What is in this cookie? Perhaps some configuration for the applet? There aren't cookies in the same way in Cocoa Touch. Perhaps you'd want to include this in a plist or other configuration file?

Comment: @JesseRusak it's dynamic, like which section has been selected on the web page. so I need to get it at different times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get cookies.

```
NSString *cookie = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.cookie"];
```

using this method can read a value directly from javascript

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [NSHTTPCookieStorage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.